# Fitting 3D points python

Tags: python, scipy

I have python code that produces a list of 3-tuples of numbers x, y and z. I would like to fit z= f(x,y) using scipy curve_fit.   Here is some non-working code

```
A = [(19,20,24), (10,40,28), (10,50,31)]

def func(x,y,a, b):
    return x*y*a + b
```

How can I get python to fit this function to the data in the list `A`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- The first argument to `func` must be the data (both x and y).
- The rest of the arguments to `func` represent the parameters.

So you need to modify your `func` a bit:

```
def func(data, a, b):
    return data[:,0]*data[:,1]*a + b
```

---

- The first argument to `curve_fit` is the function.
- The second argument is the independent `data` (`x` and `y` in the
  form of one array).
- The third argument is the dependent data (`z`).
- The fourth argument is a guess for the value of the parameters (`a`
  and `b` in this case.)

So, for example:

```
params, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, A[:,:2], A[:,2], guess)
```

---

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(19,20,24), (10,40,28), (10,50,31)])

def func(data, a, b):
    return data[:,0]*data[:,1]*a + b

guess = (1,1)
params, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(func, A[:,:2], A[:,2], guess)
print(params)
# [ 0.04919355  6.67741935]
```

Comment: This solution works if and only if x and y are characterized by the same dimension. How to generalize this code for x, y of different shape?

Comment: The answer is for arbitrary sets of x,y,z points already, so there is no shape implied. Just print A[:,:2] and A[:,2] to see that the first is the set of (x,y) points and the third are the data (z).