# Fitting 3d data

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

I would like to fit a function to a 3d data. 
 I read the data with pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
Ca = df.Ca
q = df.q
L = df.L0
```

Then, I define my 3d function (z=f(x,y)) as:

```
def func(q, Ca, l0, v0, beta):
    return l0 + q*v0*(1+beta/(q*Ca))
```

then I use curve_fit to find the best fit parameters:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
guess = (1,1,1)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, q,Ca,L, guess)
```

And it gives me the following errors:

```
ValueError: `sigma` has incorrect shape.
```

Do you know what is the mistake and how to solve it?
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413217/fitting-3d-points-python

Comment: what is `v0` in obj.func?

Comment: mistake is in passing params to [curve_fit()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a graphical 3D fitter with 3D scatter plot, 3D surface plot, and 3D contour plot.

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return a * (x**alpha) * (y**beta)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: Hi James, for consistency, would you add a few lines explaining what is the main difference in your `curve_fit` and why it doesn't work the way it is presented in the OP. Cheers

Comment: @mikuszefski - I did not analyze their code, rather I gave a different working example.

Comment: Sure, and up to know I've seen only nice examples of yours. Nevertheless, looking at the error message, your call to `curve_fit` and the according call in the OP, would allow you to state what actually went wrong. That would complete your answer, would it not?

Comment: @mikuszefski as my example code is functional for the multi-dimensional case of using curve_fit, the answer is complete by way of working example. You are welcome to state your answer in a different way, of course.

Comment: Uh...unexpected reply...I'll spare my suggestions for improvements for others in the community. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in the correctness of your Model-func & am sure in uncorrectness of the way you're passing the params. & having empty plot from James Phillips's code, just plot his Model-func to fit his data

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

x_ = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
y_ = np.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
z_ = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

def func(data, a, alpha, beta):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return a * (x**alpha) * (y**beta)

# Perform curve fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, (x_, y_), z_)

# As a quick check of whether the model may be overparameterized (resulting depedencies among dims, or Multicollinearity), calculate the condition number of the covariance matrix:
print(np.linalg.cond(pcov))

# Print optimized parameters
print(popt)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create 3D plot of the data points and the fitted curve
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x_, y_, z_, color='blue')
x_range = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y_range = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
Z = func([X, Y], *popt)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, color='red', alpha=0.7)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image]

but always pay attention to the [Condition Number](https://people.duke.edu/%7Eccc14/sta-663-2016/07_LinearAlgebra2.html#Stabilty-and-Condition-Number) of your `pcov` from fit - `np.linalg.cond(pcov)` - see in [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)

> large value is cause for concern. The diagonal elements of the
> covariance matrix, which is related to uncertainty of the fit, gives
> more information: np.diag(pcov) array([1.48814742e+29, 3.78596560e-02,
> 5.39253738e-03, 2.76417220e+28])  # may vary - in e.g.  Note that the first and last terms are much larger than the other elements, suggesting that
> the optimal values of these parameters are ambiguous and that only one
> of these parameters is needed in the model.

OR use/change scaling

P.S. [ref. curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)