# SciPy 3d curve fit error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I'm trying to curve fit a 3D function and I'm trying to start from a simple function. I started with trying to model f(x,y,z) = xyz + 1 with a test function

```
def func1(data, a, b):
    return data[:,0]*data[:,1]*data[:,2]*a + b
```

where I have copied this [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413217/fitting-3d-points-python). I think it's in this way since `curve_fit` only takes one variable so we can think of it as:

- `x = data[:,0]`
- `y = data[:,1]`
- `z = data[:,2]`

The rest of the code is as follows:

```
N = 50
L = 1
line = np.linspace(0, L, N, dtype=float)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(line, line, line)

def test(x, y, z):
    return x*y*z + 1

K = test(X, Y, Z)
guess = (1, 1)
params, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(func1, K[:,:3], K[:,3], guess)
print(params)
```

When I try to run this, I got this long message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17432/2610089433.py in <module>
      7 K = test(X, Y, Z)
      8 guess = (1, 1)
----> 9 params, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(func1, K[:,:3], K[:,3], guess)
     10 print(params)

d:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, full_output, **kwargs)
    832             raise TypeError(f"The number of func parameters={n} must not"
    833                             f" exceed the number of data points={ydata.size}")
--> 834         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    835         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    836         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

d:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    421         if maxfev == 0:
    422             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 423         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    424                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    425     else:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Is source of "data" different than the one in my Stack Overflow link? How can I fit `func1` to `test`?

Comment: What are the types of X, Y, and Z? Can you fill in the example enough that other people can run the code?

Comment: reread `curve_fit` docs, and pay close attention to the shapes - of arguments, and what the function is supposed to accept and produce.  Don't be careless about dimensions.

Comment: your `test` is nothing like `func1`

Comment: I have updated it. X, Y, Z are 3d meshgrids. Also, `func1` looks that way since I have copied the form of the fitting function on the [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413217/fitting-3d-points-python).